# SQL order by same values only insteading of alphabetic order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
  Order_ID  |  Box_ID  |  Item_ID
------------------------------------
      B     |    1     |     b
      B     |    2     |     b
      A     |    2     |     a
      A     |    3     |     a
      A     |    4     |     a
```

Now when I order the table by order ID,

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Order_ID, Box_ID;
```

the result will look like this:

```
  Order_ID  |  Box_ID  |  Item_ID
------------------------------------
      A     |    2     |     a
      A     |    3     |     a
      A     |    4     |     a
      B     |    1     |     b
      B     |    2     |     b
```

But now, I want the sql statement to first consider putting same value of Box_ID together,
such that the result will look like this:

```
  Order_ID  |  Box_ID  |  Item_ID
------------------------------------
      A     |    2     |     a
      B     |    2     |     b
// despite order_ID being B, but box_ID is equal to previous value, so group together
      A     |    3     |     a
      A     |    4     |     a
      B     |    1     |     b
```

But the following code,

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Box_ID, Order_ID
```

Will produce the following result since it lists Box_ID in alphabetical order first.

```
  Order_ID  |  Box_ID  |  Item_ID
------------------------------------
      B     |    1     |     b
      A     |    2     |     a
      B     |    2     |     b
      A     |    3     |     a
      A     |    4     |     a
```

How can I output my desired result?

Comment: By which column(s) do we know that the `Box_ID` 2 rows come first? Tables are inherently *unordered*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
order by min(order_id) over(partition by box_id), box_id
```

In earlier versions, you can use a subquery:

```
select *
from mytable t
order by
    (select min(order_id) from mytable t1 where t1.box_id = t.box_id),
    box_id
```

Comment: Okay. Seems that our MySQL server does not support OVER clause. Is there another alternative I can adopt?

Comment: @IncrediblyHandSomeSamuel: see my update.

Answer (score 0):

In order versions of MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by (select min(t2.order_id) from table t2 where t2.box_id = t.box_id),
         box_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows with most occurrences of `Box_ID` at the top, then you need this query:

```
SELECT Box_ID, COUNT(*) counter
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Box_ID
```

joined to the table like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Box_ID, COUNT(*) counter
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY Box_ID
) g ON g.Box_ID = t.Box_ID
ORDER BY g.counter DESC, Order_ID, Box_ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=851bb64d0ca0428873a143fee178a5f0).
Results:

```
> Order_ID | Box_ID | Item_ID
> :------- | -----: | :------
> A        |      2 | a      
> B        |      2 | b      
> A        |      3 | a      
> A        |      4 | a      
> B        |      1 | b
```